# How to delete this files with wildcards in ubuntu terminal

Tags: command-line, delete, wildcards

Just asking how to delete these files (below is a sample). I tried `rm -rf '*.upload'`. but they are not deleted. Please help. thanks for sharing!

sample

```
-4776d77b-15138be20a5--7fe5564294743529948392.upload
-4776d77b-15138be20a5--7fe42113893139620106164.upload
-4776d77b-15138be20a5--7fe31607666159788442489.upload    
-4776d77b-15138be20a5--7fe25373299435776669057.upload
-4776d77b-15138be20a5--7fe1207318424670693308.upload
-4776d77b-15138be20a5--7fe06041124025289424195.upload
-4776d77b-15138be20a5--7fdf746591155901247528.upload
-4776d77b-15138be20a5--7fde2651489576923158462.upload
-4776d77b-15138be20a5--7fdd2531096796717880290.upload
-4776d77b-15138be20a5--7fdc2641652764933395437.upload
-4776d77b-15138be20a5--7fdb5818566181985823473.upload
-4776d77b-15138be20a5--7fda2806206050645309611.upload
-4776d77b-15138be20a5--7fd91895678442042719781.upload
-4776d77b-15138be20a5--7fd8342875353051911187.upload
-4776d77b-15138be20a5--7fd73596962611777373454.upload
-4776d77b-15138be20a5--7fd67990174325830266540.upload
-4776d77b-15138be20a5--7fd58525749935970194788.upload
-4776d77b-15138be20a5--7fd42881375718133436679.upload
-4776d77b-15138be20a5--7fd31679085579889731530.upload
-4776d77b-15138be20a5--7fd26119620848853649755.upload
-4776d77b-15138be20a5--7fd12842363350553049954.upload
-4776d77b-15138be20a5--7fd04812945245481337635.upload
-4776d77b-15138be20a5--7fcf9164012740031565326.upload
-4776d77b-15138be20a5--7fce4881094462944077013.upload
-4776d77b-15138be20a5--7fcd1734598108195804584.upload
-4776d77b-15138be20a5--7fcc4928484618899140497.upload
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need the " ' " around your wildcard. Just use `rm -rf *.upload`. And if they are just files you don't need the `-r` option.

EDIT:

Actually, because you have a "-" at the beginning of your file's name, the command line tries to interpret it as an option for the command, messing things ups. What you need to do is to select the file using `./` like so: `rm ./*.upload`. I can't explain more why it does that, but this should work.

Comment: thanks shadowMitia for quick response. 
but still does not delete, instead comment appear, by the way im already in root:

# rm -rf *.upload
rm: invalid option -- 1
Try `rm ./-17e0ff18-1516c3dc17f--7fd17787933978606484871.upload' to remove the file `-17e0ff18-1516c3dc17f--7fd17787933978606484871.upload'.
Try `rm --help' for more information.

Comment: rm -/*.upload
rm: invalid option -- /

Comment: My bad, spelling mistake. Should be a "." not a "-".

Comment: thanks! it work in------------>    rm ./*.upload    thanks again!